# Setting a next value for a linkedlist function

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm looking at [This LeetCode Question](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/) about LinkedList and there's something I don't understand about [the answer](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/solutions/127833/add-two-numbers/).

In the code below, I have copied the answer from above and added a comment in the place I want to refer to:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

def addTwoNumbers(l1,l2):
    dummyHead = ListNode(0)
    curr = dummyHead
    carry = 0
    while l1 != None or l2 != None or carry != 0:
        l1Val = l1.val if l1 else 0
        l2Val = l2.val if l2 else 0
        columnSum = l1Val + l2Val + carry
        carry = columnSum // 10
        newNode = ListNode(columnSum % 10)
        #####################
        curr.next = newNode #
        curr = newNode      #    <- Part 1
        ##############################
        l1 = l1.next if l1 else None # <- Part 2
        l2 = l2.next if l2 else None #
        ##############################
    return dummyHead.next

l1 = ListNode(1)
l2 = ListNode(2)
print(addTwoNumbers(l1=l1,l2=l2).val)
```

1. In the section I marked as `Part 1`, why set `curr.next` to `newNode` and then completely overwrite it with `curr = newNode`? I checked, and it seems like it overwrites the value completely, and thus removing the `next` in `curr`.
2. In the section I marked as `Part 2`, doesn't the following line: `l1 = l1.next` overwrite everything yet again?
3. How does returning `dummyHead.next` works? This value wasn't modified, it's just an empty list in the beginning

I tried to debug but I still haven't gotten much out of it. I'm trying to learn LinkedList from this example and would appreciate any help.
Huge thanks ahead!

Comment: Basic thing to remember about Python is that variables hold references to objects. Therefore e. g. `curr = dummyHead` copies a reference. Both variables refer to the very same object then. Setting the attribute with `curr.next = newNode` also sets the attribute `dummyHead.next` (until "curr" is set to refer to another object).

Comment: *"yet everything again?"*: I don't understand this phrase in your second point. What do you mean?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for the response! I didn't know that about objects in Python. I thought that it just takes the current state and stores it in a new object. Seems like if that's the case it's redundant to create the `curr` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why set `curr.next` to `newNode` and then completely overwrite it with `curr = newNode`?

These are two different type of assignment. The first -- assigning to `curr.next` -- **mutates** whatever object that `curr` is referencing. The second -- `curr = newNode` -- merely changes what `curr` references to. It doesn't mutate the data structure. It may help to visualise what happens. Let's say `curr` references a `ListNode` instance with value 1:

```
curr
  │
┌─┴──────────┐
│ val: 1     │
│ next: None │
└────────────┘
```

And `newNode` was just created with a value 2:

```
curr              newNode
  │                 │
┌─┴──────────┐    ┌─┴──────────┐
│ val: 1     │    │ val: 2     │
│ next: None │    │ next: None │
└────────────┘    └────────────┘
```

Then the first assignment -- `curr.next = newNode` will accomplish this:

```
curr              newNode
  │                 │
┌─┴──────────┐    ┌─┴──────────┐
│ val: 1     │    │ val: 2     │
│ next: ──────────┤ next: None │
└────────────┘    └────────────┘
```

And the second assignment, leads to this state:

```
                  curr newNode
                    │    │
┌────────────┐    ┌─┴────┴─────┐
│ val: 1     │    │ val: 2     │
│ next: ──────────┤ next: None │
└────────────┘    └────────────┘
```

The same would have happened, if the second assignment would have been `curr = curr.next`, since at that point `curr.next` and `newNode` reference the same object. This should also explain the rationale for your second point concerning `l1 = l1.next`. This merely traverses one step through a linked list with a variable. It doesn't affect that linked list itself.

> How does returning `dummyHead.next` works? This value wasn't modified, it's just an empty list in the beginning.

The list *was* modified. But it happened via a different variable... `curr`. Note how initially `curr` references the *same* object as `dummyHead`, and then in the loop, the assignment to `curr.next` is setting the `next` attribute that `dummyHead` references, so that now `dummyHead.next` references a list with one element. And `curr` will move on to reference that element, and again set its `next` attribute, making that linked list having 2 nodes, ...etc